# Can't log into Active Admin. Any way to create an admin user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

When I try to log in with the default admin user, I get "invalid email or password." Is there a way to create a user with code and try to log in that way?

I can log in on my live website, but not locally. My development code matches exactly what is on production.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can run a `rails console` on your development server, and create a new admin user in the console itself.

The following is a typical sequence of such commands (change them according to your setup):

```
user = AdminUser.new
user.email = "<your email>"
user.password = "<your password>"
user.save
```

That will create the required admin for you. :)

Comment: Damn you Stoic! You beat me to it :) But I guess it is AdminUser (not 100% sure)

Comment: You mean my development server, right? Since that's where my login is failing?

Comment: Yeah, in that case, the development server.
@sytycs: I will let you have your chance on some other question, then ;)

Comment: Okay. Let me give that a shot.

Comment: @sytycs: that depends what resource I am using for ActiveAdmin. In my case, I prefer `User`, and therefore.

Comment: @Stoic  - When I try to do `user.admin = true`, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method `admin=' for #<User:0x00000101ec62b8>`

Comment: @Stoic sure, I was just adding this in case OP is wondering.

Comment: @DylanRichards: as I said, this depends on your setup. If you are using the default ActiveAdmin setup, please run the updated code.

Comment: Okay. Let me try this out.

Answer (score 3):

another way is to place [this](https://github.com/gregbell/demo.activeadmin.info/blob/master/db/seeds.rb) file into `db` directory and then run

```
rake db:seed
```

or in console

```
Rails.application.load_seed
```

there you can see how `AdminUser` is created, as well

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: This is the Rails way to do it!